# No consigo insertar la imagen después del input con JS

Tags: javascript

El HTML (creo los inputs):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre" required>
<input type="email" placeholder="Escribe tu Email" required/>
<textarea placeholder="Escribe aquí el contenido de tu mensaje"></textarea>
```

Y el JavaScript para el input email (con resolver este ya hago los otros):

```
var email = document.querySelector("input[type='email']")

function removeElement(element) {
  for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    element[i].parentNode.removeChild(element[i]);
  }
}

function borrarEmail() {
  var parArea = document.getElementsByClassName("remove5");
  var parArea2 = document.getElementsByClassName("remove6");

  if (parArea.length > 0 && parArea2 > 0) {
    removeElement(parArea);
    removeElement(parArea2);
  }
}

email.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  if (this.value == "" || this.value.indexOf("@") == -1 || this.value.indexOf(".") == -1) {
    borrarEmail();
    email.setAttribute("style", "background: pink; border-color: red");
    var parrafo5 = document.createElement("p");
    parrafo5.classList.add("remove5");
    parrafo5.innerHTML = "Bad Email";
    var emailConf = email.parentNode;
    emailConf.insertBefore(parrafo5, email);
    parrafo5.setAttribute("style", "color: red");
  } else {
    borrarEmail();
    email.setAttribute("style", "background: #C8FDD4; border-color: #52FD8B");
    var parrafo6 = document.createElement("img");
    parrafo6.classList.add("remove6");
    var emailCheck = document.getElementsByClassName("remove6");
    emailCheck.src = "./img/check.png";
    var emailConf1 = email.parentNode;
    emailConf1.insertChildAfter(parrafo6, email);
  }
});
```

Lo que hago es checkar que si el campo esta vacio añadirle estilo al input y un texto, (eso funciona), pero al añadirle una imagen despues, no consigo que funcione.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para insertar un elemento inmediatamente después de otro utiliza:

```
elemento.parentNode.insertBefore(nuevo_elemento, elemento.nextSibling);
```

Esto quiere decir, insertar justo antes del elemento siguiente. No es muy elegante pero a falta de un metodo insertAfter (no existe) funciona bien.

Aquí te dejo el código corregido, hice otros cambios ya que la eliminación del mensaje de error (o el checkmark) no funcionaban bien.

```js
var email = document.querySelector("input[type='email']")


function removeElement(element) {
  if (element.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
      element[i].parentNode.removeChild(element[i]);
     }
  }
}

function borrarIndicadores() {
  var parArea = document.getElementsByClassName("con_error");
  var parArea2 = document.getElementsByClassName("sin_error");
  removeElement(parArea);
  removeElement(parArea2);
}

email.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  if (this.value == "" || this.value.indexOf("@") == -1 || this.value.indexOf(".") == -1) {
    borrarIndicadores();
    email.setAttribute("style", "background: pink; border-color: red");
    var parrafo5 = document.createElement("p");
    parrafo5.classList.add("con_error");
    parrafo5.innerHTML = "Bad Email";
    var emailConf = email.parentNode;
    emailConf.insertBefore(parrafo5, email);
    parrafo5.setAttribute("style", "color: red");
  } else {
    borrarIndicadores();
    email.setAttribute("style", "background: #C8FDD4; border-color: #52FD8B");
    var image = document.createElement("img");
    image.classList.add("sin_error");
    image.style.width = "20px";
    image.style.height = "20px";
    image.src = "http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/download/moth-green/check-mark-3-512.gif";
    email.parentNode.insertBefore(image, email.nextSibling);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre" required>
<input type="email" placeholder="Escribe tu Email" required>
<textarea placeholder="Escribe aquí el contenido de tu mensaje"></textarea>
```

Aquí te dejo una version revisada que incluye todos lo campos, hice algunas mejoras (refactorize los metodos repetidos) y corregi otros bugs menores.

https://jsfiddle.net/efgqkn1k/2/

Comment: deberias borrar el msg de error al printarlo, sino se muestra repetido

Comment: Gracias me funciono el código, pero al extenderlo me surgio un nuevo error, edite la entrada con el nuevo código.

Comment: Hola @Juan! y bienvenido! Quería comentarte que no debes cambiar el requerimiento de la pregunta, pues resulta confuso a otros usuarios. Lo mejor es un caso así, es que realizes una nueva pregunta. Esta vez voy a  ayudarte (en una hora o algo así, por que estoy trabajando :) .. pero en el futuro considera la opción de agregar una pregunta nueva.

Comment: Gracias @rnrneverdies, entendido

Comment: @Juan edite la pregunta y revertí tu edición, así la pregunta no es confusa.

Comment: Muchas gracias @rnrneverdies tengo que verlo con calma para entenderlo bien. Está muy optimizado, Gracias.